# semantic-release: fatal: tag 'vX.Y.Z' already exists

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-tag, semantic-release

Trying to set up [semantic-release/gitlab](https://github.com/semantic-release/gitlab), I'm getting this in my GitLab logs,

```
Error: Command failed with exit code 128: git tag v1.0.0 2c30602010d7d9f26cc0880b988ff9de6405daa5
fatal: tag 'v1.0.0' already exists
    at makeError (/builds/myProject/angular-validators/node_modules/semantic-release/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:60:11)
    at handlePromise (/builds/myProject/angular-validators/node_modules/semantic-release/node_modules/execa/index.js:118:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async tag (/builds/myProject/angular-validators/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/git.js:224:3)
    at async run (/builds/myProject/angular-validators/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:191:5)
    at async module.exports (/builds/myProject/angular-validators/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:260:22)
    at async module.exports (/builds/myProject/angular-validators/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js:55:5) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 128: git tag v1.0.0 2c30602010d7d9f26cc0880b988ff9de6405daa5',
  command: 'git tag v1.0.0 2c30602010d7d9f26cc0880b988ff9de6405daa5',
```

But when I check out my project on GitLab,

```
https://gitlab/myGroup/myProject/-/tags
```

It shows no tags. When I view my pipline's output, I see

```
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/myGroup/myProject/.git/
Checking out fc225500 as master...
Removing .npm/
Removing node_modules/
Skipping Git submodules setup
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change your "Git Strategy", to clone. There is no way to get past this error or clear the cache without doing this.

[Find the instructions on the GitLab documentation for choosing a Git strategy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#choose-the-default-git-strategy). There are two methods they support detailed above,

- You can specify this in the project settings ([instructions on the doc page above](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#choose-the-default-git-strategy))
- or by specifying a `GIT_STRATEGY` variable in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.